# Open source scripts for Oracle health check?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i, plsql

I want to put together some scripts to run an automated health check of Oracle 9i and 10g databases. Before I start from scratch, I was wondering if anyone know of any available open source scripts that I could use as a base for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to metalink - document 136697.1 has a healthcheck script.

Comment: Metalink is all gone, all that is left is the sucky My Oracle Support. Hate it. I found the note, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important part of the health check is not the data extraction, but data analysis.
We have our scripts built around statspacks, as they provide most reliable results and statistics.

http://www.leaderside.com/oracle-health-check/oracle-healthcheck-2

[Learn more here.](http://www.leaderside.com/oracle-health-check/oracle-healthcheck-2)

Answer (score 0):

Tim Hall has a great site for Oracle resources: [oracle-base.com](http://oracle-base.com/dba/DBACategories.php). I would bet there's a lot in there you could use.

Comment: oracle-base.com is certainly a good oracle resource, but I've been unable to find any health check scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.evdbt.com/tools.htm has a whole bunch of healthcheck/monitoring/performance related scripts. Some of them are quite advanced but maybe  they're worth a look in case you want to set up something more "powerful".

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10g + the inbuilt DBCONSOLE website has quite an extensive set of monitoring and health checking features.

I'd take a look at those before looking at external scripts.

Comment: We need to support multiple platforms. Some customers have enterprise manager, some use the dbconsole, some have third party tools. What I need to develop is something I can run at any database without too many dependencies. The goal being to reduce the time required to create a complete health check report.